# Using forms in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am creating a website and have two forms. The database I have has authors and titles. What I want to do is when I click the author in my choice field, I want the titles to be filtered so the user can only select those. How would I do this?

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    author = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Article.objects.all())

    title = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Article.objects.filter(author=author))

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('author','title')
```

When I click the author name, the title still remains blank. What should I do?

Below is my model

```
class Article (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need a relation between the article and author. If you have models like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

Than an `Article` belongs to an `Author` and a `Author` can have many `Article`s.

A modelForm based on the `Author` model lets you add (or modify) an author. A modelForm based on `Article` lets you add (or modify) an article. Thats all very useful but not in this case. We need a normal form with [ModelChoiceFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) to select author and article:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.Form):
    author = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Author.objects.all())
    article = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Article.objects.all())
```

This form will have a select widget for both `author` and `article` field. It let's you select one of each. It will render all authors and all articles to template. That's okay if you have a few, but will be problematic with many entries.

The next part is to filter the article choices. The answer to this is a bit harder. Because it depends on your project requirements.

- You might want to write some JavaScript to filter the select fields
  based on author.
- You might want to add a validator for fields that
  depend on each other.
- You might not want to load all articles in
  advance and might want to use Ajax techniques to load the articles
  belonging to an author.
- You might want to use the FormWizard to split your form in multiple pages/steps.
- ...

Comment: What I want is the fields dynamically changing without submitting the form. In other words as I click the author name in the form, the options in the title form should change. The choices in the title form should be titles from that particular author. Does that make sense?

Comment: I added my model file. in case that helps you